# How do I prompt metamask to open?

Tags: metamask, javascript

I'm using react and javascript. For whatever reason, I've tried a few methods and it doesn't seem to be opening metamask.

```
await window.ethereum.enable();
```

and

```
window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
```

But in the second instance it has no clue what web3 is.

Answer (score 1):

```
import Web3 from 'web3';
```

At the top of the file and then during a componentwillmount or whatnot, these lines...

```
window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
await window.ethereum.enable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Metamask extension loads the ethereum provider on window.
The following code will throw a MetaMask prompt to enable connection:

```
if(window.ethereum){
    ethereum.enable().then(function(acc){
        App.account = acc[0];
    });
}
```